# Was a House Elf able to perform Unforgivable Curses?

Tags: harry-potter, unforgivable-curse

In other words, how dangerous could an out-of-control mad House Elf be?

Comment: Example: What Dobby did to Lucius :)

Comment: @Faizan I don't think that that was one of the Unforgivable Curses.

Comment: When did I say it was an Unforgivable Curse? It was merely a glimpse of what "out-of-control mad house elf" could do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no canon confirmation either way, in the books, Pottermore or interviews.

All we DO know is that:

- Wizards suspected Winky of casting Mordmorde spell, which is a pretty dark and powerfull spell even if not an Unforgivable. Therefore, it's not impossible for a house-elf - at least with a wand - to cast known powerful Wizarding spells. This means that Unforgivables are at least plausible.
- House elf magic is pretty powerful in general (apparating in no-apparate spell, blasting back malfoy, intercepting Harry's mail by Dobby, tracking down and taking down a fully trained Order member Mundungus, surviving drinking Voldemort's cave potion). This would mean that they would definitely have enough power.
- Specific to Unforgivables, house-elves clearly are able to feel the strong negative emotions required to power Cruciatus and Avada Kedavra (witness Dobby attacking Lucius. Or Kreacher's emotions about mudbloods and traitors - if he was ordered to by Bella or Narcissa I have little doubt he could have Crucioed someone).

So, the PotterBusters rates this theory as "unknown, but not implausible".

Comment: What is PotterBusters?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythBusters#Outcomes_of_the_experiments